# Invariant Violation: A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself contains more than one VirtualizedList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

The complete error is:

> Invariant Violation: A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself
>   contains more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the
>   parent list. You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list.

Every single one of my `FlatList` components has a `keyExtractor` prop. Every item within the `List` from `react-native-elements` component has a key prop.

Could anyone shed any light on the meaning of this problem?

Answer (score 16):

As the error says "You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list." A prop like listKey="someUniqueString" to FlatList fixed this error for me

Comment: I have tried this, but it is still giving me the same error. Could you provide some other solution

Comment: If you haven't found a solution yet, try giving each of the nested flatlist a unique value using index or some unique value. that might solve the issue

Answer (score 14):

I got this error when using nested flat lists.I use listKey instead of keyExtractor.

```
**listKey={(item, index) => 'D' + index.toString()}**
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `ListKey`  and `keyExtractor` props in the `FlatList` to prevent this error OR warning

Example :

```
  listKey={(item, index) => `_key${index.toString()}`}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `_key${index.toString()}`}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using FaltList as a nested list of any other FlatList or SectionList then you have to pass a unique value to this props 
listKey

> listKey={this._keyExtractor}

```
_keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
return this.props.index+"_"+index+'_'+item.id+"_"+moment().valueOf().toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
<FlatList 
  data={[{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]} 
  renderItem={
    ({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>
  } 
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
  listKey="YourListName" //put here list name
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error. But fixed using unique string

```
listKey={moment().valueOf().toString()}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `nestedFlatList` you need to add `listKey` property